# Use of unassigned local variable that is assigned

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement, for-loop, unassigned-variable

The below code runs a 'for' loop to create months 1 through 12 then names each month Jan through Dec according to their number.  That pieces compiles fine.  At the bottom where I try to write the month name on the screen is where it is failing.  It says "use of unassigned local variable 'monthName'; however monthName was just used previously and is declared above.  Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
{
    string monthName;
    double monthlyProd = .1 * dProdRate;
    double monthlySales = .07 * dSalesRate;
    if (month == 1) { monthName = "Jan"; }
    if (month == 2) { monthName = "Feb"; monthlyProd = 0; }
    if (month == 3) { monthName = "Mar"; }
    if (month == 4) { monthName = "Apr"; }
    if (month == 5) { monthName = "May"; }
    if (month == 6) { monthName = "Jun"; monthlyProd = 0; }
    if (month == 7) { monthName = "Jul"; }
    if (month == 8) { monthName = "Aug"; }
    if (month == 9) { monthName = "Sep"; monthlySales = (.15 * dSalesRate); }
    if (month == 10) { monthName = "Oct"; }
    if (month == 11) { monthName = "Nov"; }
    if (month == 22) { monthName = "Dec"; monthlySales = (.15 * dSalesRate); }
}
dEndingInventory += dPreviousProd - dPreviousSales;
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1,15}{2,15}{3,15}", monthName, monthlyProd, monthlySales, dEndingInventory);
```

Comment: You need to declare `monthName` outside the loop as well as other two.

Comment: Actually, it seems more likely that that `Console.WriteLine` should be moved inside the loop. Otherwise, what is the point of assigning a value to `monthName`? At the end of the loop it will always be `"Dec"`.

Comment: FYI whether you actually declare any of the variables outside of the loop or not, the fact is that all of them are being overwritten by the last `if` statement they are involved in inside the for loop, meaning `month == 11` for monthName, `month == 9` for monthlySales... Strange code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that `month` can only take the values 1 to 12 inclusive but the compiler is not that smart. If say `month` is 0 then the variable `monthName` is never assigned a value and that is what the compiler is complaining about. To fix it simply initialize the variable when you declare it:

```
string monthName = null;
```

Also, there is something fishy about your code because `monthName` is used outside the loop where it is declared but I assume that this is a typo because the code as it stands now will not give you the error you are asking about.

Comment: It's a shame all the other answers are nonsense.

Comment: Hi Martin,
Thanks for the help.  I was getting the error if the monthName was inside the loop or out so I was stuck.  I initialized the variable where it is now, and it works.  (Fixed another error too: month 12 is December, not month 22 :) 
Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You have declared the monthName, monthlyProd,monthlySales under the scope of For Loop and trying to use those variables out of the scope of For Loop. You should declare variables before for loop-

```
string monthName;
double monthlyProd = .1 * dProdRate;
double monthlySales = .07 * dSalesRate;

for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
{

    if (month == 1) { monthName = "Jan"; }
    if (month == 2) { monthName = "Feb"; monthlyProd = 0; }
    if (month == 3) { monthName = "Mar"; }
    if (month == 4) { monthName = "Apr"; }
    if (month == 5) { monthName = "May"; }
    if (month == 6) { monthName = "Jun"; monthlyProd = 0; }
    if (month == 7) { monthName = "Jul"; }
    if (month == 8) { monthName = "Aug"; }
    if (month == 9) { monthName = "Sep"; monthlySales = (.15 * dSalesRate); }
    if (month == 10) { monthName = "Oct"; }
    if (month == 11) { monthName = "Nov"; }
    if (month == 22) { monthName = "Dec"; monthlySales = (.15 * dSalesRate); }
}
dEndingInventory += dPreviousProd - dPreviousSales;
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1,15}{2,15}{3,15}", monthName, monthlyProd, monthlySales, dEndingInventory);
```

Comment: Will this get rid of the compiler error _use of unassigned local variable_ which this question is about? No, it will not.